# Можно ли использовать *ngIf и *ngFor одновременно

Tags: html, npm, angular7

Можно ли использовать в одном селекторе в Angular7 использовать     *ngIf и *ngFor как тут

```
<button  *ngFor="let item of products" (click)="toogleCollapse()" *ngIf="isCollapse" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{{item}}</button>
```

Comment: а ты попробовал так использовать? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, нельзя, нужна обёртка, например такая

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isCollapse">
    <button *ngFor="let item of products" (click)="toogleCollapse()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{{item}}</button>
</ng-container>
```